# How to inject "Chart.js" in my module?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

This is my Html. I have given paths like this

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="../../Content/Scripts/Script/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../Content/Scripts/Script/Chart.js"></script>
      <script src="../../Content/Scripts/Script/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../Content/Scripts/Script/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"> </script>
      <script src="../../Content/Scripts/Controllers/graphController.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
       <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="financeAnalyticsController" class="support-section">
       {{a}}
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my script I wrote

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ "chart.js","ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.typeahead",]);

app.controller('financeAnalyticsController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {
   $scope.a="testing";
});
```

When I am using in my application it is giving error

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

How to solve this error?

Comment: The injector error seems unrelated to your question. You don't have to inject another `chart.js`. Your code looks fine, Could u set up a plunkr?

Comment: if you are using chartjs lib it's not an angularjs module.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using a different version of angular-chart.js. Try using **`angularCharts`** instead of **`chart.js`** as the dependency module name, like so ...

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["angularCharts", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.typeahead"]);

app.controller('financeAnalyticsController', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
   $scope.a="testing";
});
```

**or**, use [**this**](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js) version of [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

see a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vvoqkk57/)

Comment: actually I want inject chart.js only why because In my application I used chart.js for graphs

Comment: then you can use `chart.js` as the dependency module name.

Comment: that is why I injected in module

Comment: ok, but didn't it work when you change the module name to `angularCharts`?